# PyCharm Edu vs PyCharm CE with EduTools Plugin

Tags: windows, python, ide, comparison

To be blunt, are they the same? Does PyCharm Edu provide something that the EduTools Plugin for other JetBrain IDE's doesn't? I am a new teacher that is wondering what the difference between these two items is. Currently, I have been playing around with PyCharm CE (and IntelliJ IDEA) with EduTools.

I believe that PyCharm Edu was the de facto Education software via JetBrains, but since the release of Kotlin, they have expanded on the EduTools plugin and it seems like both methods provide the same experience (basically).

Am I wrong? A Google search doesn't appear to provide clear information about the difference between the two.

Comment: Nobody can answer what *the best recommendation* is if you do not tell us what your criteria are. Can you add those?

Comment: @JanDoggen Sorry, I typed that after the fact and actually meant "difference". I have found very little online about the differences and they appear to be the same. I am wondering if they are the same or not. And what those major differences are

Comment: I am asking because I thought that PyCharm Edu would be a better solution, as education is its niche; however, I have been using EduTool Plugin and it seems to have feature parity. So whats the point of PyCharm Edu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PyCharm EduTools page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10081-edutools):

> All the features available in PyCharm Edu are also available in the EduTools plugin.

So PyCharm CE + EduTools is the exact same as PyCharm Edu in terms of functionality. Pycharm Edu is just a batteries-included distribution of PyCharmCE with EduTools.

Comment: OK, I see the side note. From more testing, it also appears that PyCharm Edu is a stripped down PyCharm CE. So that might make it easier for 1st-time learners. I think I will stick with PyCharm CE + EduTools Plugin for now